# Google Maps MVCArray With Fusion Tables

Tags: arrays, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, heatmap

Probably a rookie question, currently I've created a heatmap-layer HTML file using hard coded locations within my HTML file.  Below is a sample of my code.  What I'm trying to do is replace the "heatMapData" with data from a Fusion Table.  The goal is for the map to update whenever the Fusion Table is updated.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
var heatMapData = [{location: new google.maps.LatLng(42.071523,-72.624257), weight:4.2},
                   {location: new google.maps.LatLng(42.37686,-72.46914), weight:1.6}
                  ];

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.82, -99.408660),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatMapData);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: pointArray
        });

        heatmap.setMap(map);
      }
```

Using the example site Dr Molle posted I can't seem to render the heat map when I change the Fusion Table ID reference (it has the same column names: Lat, Long, Hits).  Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Test Map</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">



      <script type='text/javascript' src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization&.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.82, -99.408660),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        //query the fusiontable via ajax    
        $.ajax(
                {
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  url     : 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query',
                  data    : {
                              sql:'SELECT Lat,Long,Hits \
                                   from 1jsYEXL-Bz0dse02Llf9cUquXkU0MqH6JlUyNhLE',
                              key:'AIzaSyCoiF1SlcuQPqoRdbP58ZCi3YrPx4wvMfg'
                            },
                  success:  function(data){
                             var heatMapData=[];
                               //prepare the data
                             $.each(data.rows,function(i,r){
                               heatMapData.push({
                                   location:new google.maps.LatLng(r[0],r[1]),
                                   weight:Number(r[2])
                                 });
                             });
                               //create the weighted heatmap
                              new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                                  data: heatMapData,map:map
                                  });
                            }
               });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 800px; width: 1000px;"></div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Do you know that there are also [**FusionTable Heatmaps**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTablesHeatmaps)?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to use the WeightedLocation object.  My goal is to create a weighted heatmap driven from data in a Fusion Table in order to make updating easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may query the fusionTable and create the data for the layer from the response.

Example(using jQuery and ajax):

```
$.ajax(
                {
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  url     : 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query',
                  data    : {
                              sql:'SELECT Lat,Long,Hits \
                                   from 1LL0eWI89nGxJ17XZDbWKsWahPyzQCAH8MHoAPSk',
                              key:'yourKey'
                            },
                  success:  function(data){
                             var heatMapData=[];
                               //prepare the data
                             $.each(data.rows,function(i,r){
                               heatMapData.push({
                                   location:new google.maps.LatLng(r[0],r[1]),
                                   weight:Number(r[2])
                                 });
                             });
                               //create the weighted heatmap
                              new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                                  data: heatMapData,map:map
                                  });
                            }
               });
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/RxMdf/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/RxMdf/)

**Note:** when you use ajax you must use JSONP to bypass the browsers same-origin-restrictions.
Of course you may request the data also on serverside.

However, if it's usable in your application depends on the amount of data, because the complete data(location and weight) must be downloaded by the client.

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish this without using ajax?  I'm having a tough time getting this to work properly.  The demo you posted is great, exactly what I want.  I attempted to use that same code from the demo, only replacing the fusion table with my own fusion table and I can't seem to render any results to the map.

Comment: You can also do it without ajax, download the data on serverside and make the data available to javascript. When you use the demo with your table you also must modify the names of the cols(in the demo Lat,Long,Hits)

Comment: See updated example above Dr Molle.  I updated the Fusion Table ID and a few other options from the example, but can't seem to render the heatmap layer.

Comment: 2 issues: **1.** the column-names are case-sensitive, they must be `LAT,LONG,HITS` for your table. **2.** You have copied the key, but this is my key which only works with particular referers, e.g. my jsfiddle-account. Create an own google-maps-account and use your own key.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've updated the column names (LAT, LONG, HITS) and I've replaced your API key with my API key.  Still didn't render anything on the map.  Sorry for all the rookie questions, I thank you in advance.

Comment: There must be something wrong with my key when I update the code with my key (AIzaSyBLfVaeoTIr2gup-PRL9a9g53JOJ1erNFQ). Do I need a different type of key?

Comment: did you activate the service "Fusion Tables API" in API-console->services?

Comment: Genius.  I can't thank you enough for your help.  You've gone above and beyond, thanks so much!